# SonarQube analysis failed

Tags: php, symfony, sonarqube

I'm working with SonarQube 6.1 and I'm on a Symfony 2.8 project.

When I run an analyse with sonar-scanner, I get an ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL but the result is failed with in my logs :

```
Error Details

org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException: Visit of Component {key=ThisIsMyFuckingProjectKeyFor:XXXXXX:src/AdminBundle/AdminBundle.php,type=FILE} failed
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.ExecuteVisitorsStep.execute(ExecuteVisitorsStep.java:51)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:84)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:57)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The manDays for language php is not a valid long number
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.qualitymodel.RatingSettings.getDevCost(RatingSettings.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.qualitymodel.QualityModelMeasuresVisitor.computeDevelopmentCost(QualityModelMeasuresVisitor.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.qualitymodel.QualityModelMeasuresVisitor.visitFile(QualityModelMeasuresVisitor.java:119)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.PathAwareVisitorWrapper.visitFile(PathAwareVisitorWrapper.java:66)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitNode(VisitorsCrawler.java:129)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:100)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.qualitymodel.RatingSettings.getDevCost(RatingSettings.java:84)
    ... 27 more
```

Do you have an idea for this error ?

Answer (score 5):

The error `The manDays for language php is not a valid long number` means that the field `Development cost` of property `Language specific parameters` has an incorrect value for PHP in Administration > General Settings > Technical Debt. You should reset value or put a valid number.